# Use GROUPBY measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, measure, summarize

I have a table that lists different chracteristics in funtion of the distance. At each position, there is either a vlue or not, and often the only a part of the values are filled.

I want to 'summarize' the table, such that when I select some category, the table summarize the state in function of [distance from] and [distance to] if the characteristics are the same.

To do so, I just made a measure min(distance), max(distance). However, all the in between blanks parts are not shown.

Any of how I can calculte min/max to summarize the data and group by such that everything is shown ?

Input =

| Distance from | Distance to | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NULL | a |
| 2 | 4 | b | a |
| 4 | 10 | b | a |

Output (if col1 and col2 are selected)=

| Distance from | Distance to | Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NULL | a |
| 2 | 10 | b | a |

Output (if only col1) is selected=

| Distance from | Distance to | Col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | NULL |
| 2 | 10 | b |

Comment: could you add the example table and the desired output as example? It is not clear what you are asking

Comment: Just added a small example